# If $A$ a $3 \times 3$ matrix, find $e^A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $$A = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & -1& -1\\ -1 & -1&-1\\-1&-1&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Find $e^A$. Any ideas?

Comment: something that should help is that $A^{n}=3^{n-1}A$.

Comment: Actually it should be $A^{n}=(-3)^{n-1}A$.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I accidentally had an extra $-1$ in my calculation

Answer (score 0):

As hinted at above, you want to find a way of writing $A^n=k_nA$ for $k_n\in\mathbb{R}$. Then use the Taylor expansion

$$ e^A=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A^n}{n!}=I+A\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{k_n}{n!}\right) $$

Alternatively, if you can't evaluate the sum, you can diagonalise the matrix to get $A=UDU^{-1}$, then it follows from Sylvester's formula that $e^A=Ue^DU^{-1}$. Evaluating $e^D$ for a diagonal matrix $D$ is easy - you simply raise all of the diagonal components to the power of $e$.

Useful:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixExponential.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential

Answer (score 0):

I think that

$$
\textbf{A}^n = (-3)^{n-1} \textbf{A} = -\frac{1}{3} (-3)^n \textbf{A}
$$

So

$$
\exp(A) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A^n}{k!} = -\frac{1}{3} \textbf{I} - \frac{1}{3} \Big[ \exp(-3) - 1 \Big]\textbf{A}
$$

Comment: Really? That's what I had to do? The professor didn't even include that in the notes and she asked us to answer that in the exam. I didn't do this question for the exam but I was curious on how I could have done it.